# Algorithm to shuffle array without any same position

Tags: shuffle

Suppose that there is an array `a[n]` without any duplicate elements, i.e., `a[i] != a[j]` for each `i != j`. I want to shuffle this array to be `b[n]` randomly, and `b[i] != a[i]` for each `i`. Is that any fast implementation?

Comment: Do you want `b[i] != a[i]` or do you want random?  Random will sometimes cause elements to appear in the same position, that's too be expected.

Comment: The functionality you're looking for is called a *derangement*, that might help you to search for existing algorithms.